# List adding overwrting again and again

Tags: java, arraylist

Below is my JAVA method

```
public static List<Match<String, String>> Decider
    (List<Preference<String, String>> hospitalPrefs,List<Preference<String, String>> studentPrefs)
{
    Match<String, String> matching = new Match<String, String>(null, null);
    List<Match<String, String>> matcher = new ArrayList<Match<String, String>>();

    /** Matching the preference of the hospital with the student */

    for(int hospitalLoop = 0;hospitalLoop < hospitalPrefs.size(); hospitalLoop++)
    {
        String hospitalPreferrer = hospitalPrefs.get(hospitalLoop).getPreferrer();
        String hospitalPreferred = hospitalPrefs.get(hospitalLoop).getPreferred();
        int hospitalValue = hospitalPrefs.get(hospitalLoop).getValue();

        for(int studentLoop = 0;studentLoop < studentPrefs.size();studentLoop++)
        {
            String studentPreferrer = studentPrefs.get(studentLoop).getPreferrer();
            String studentPreferred = studentPrefs.get(studentLoop).getPreferred();
            int studentValue = studentPrefs.get(studentLoop).getValue();

            if(hospitalPreferred.equals(studentPreferrer)
                    && hospitalPreferrer.equals(studentPreferred)
                    && hospitalValue == studentValue)
            {
                System.out.println(hospitalPreferred + "," + studentPreferred);
                matching.setItem1(hospitalPreferred);
                matching.setItem2(studentPreferred);
                matcher.add(matching);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return matcher;
}
```

matcher variable is overwrite the list. I am confused about it.

Something like if I am adding
        a,b,c.

In the matcher variable it is adding 
        c,c,c

I am confused where I m going wrong.

Thanks !!!

Comment: (1) Where and how are you checking the content of `matcher`? (2) Where's `getItem1()` method from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating instance of `matching` before loop and then adding the same instance to your collection. You probably wanted to create matching inside the loop:

```
    ................
    System.out.println(hospitalPreferred + "," + studentPreferred);
    Match<String, String> matching = new Match<String, String>(null, null);
    matching.setItem1(hospitalPreferred);
    matching.setItem2(studentPreferred);
    matcher.add(matching);
    break;        
    ................
```

Answer (score 0):

You intialize matching once and then change its value.  You need

```
matching = new Match<String,String>();
```

somwhere in your loops.

Answer (score 0):

You're just adding the same `matching` over an over again.

If I were you, I'd move

```
Match<String, String> matching = new Match<String, String>(null, null);
```

to right before

```
matching.setItem1(hospitalPreferred);
matching.setItem2(studentPreferred);
matcher.add(matching);
```